# Sqlite Data base in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to read my SQLite database with in my iPhone application I am able to read some fields but how to read Text fields data type. I wrote this line of code...

```
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
```

But it gives me an error. Can anyone help me on this, or help me out with a data type compatible with Objective C?

Comment: "It gives me error"? What error, exactly? Error messages usually have pretty good clues to what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, please post more details about your code and your error.

Answer (score 0):

Always consider checking that sqlite3_column_text does not return NULL before using it.

There is a big probability that this is the cause of your error/exception.